# What climate would Kumari Kandam have (a mythical continent on the Indian Ocean)?

Tags: alternate-history, climate, geology, flora, mythology

[image: Kumari History]

Kumari Kandam was another mythical continent. It was believed to be host to an ancient Tamil civilization. Such a land was mentioned in ancient Tamil writings. Europeans picked up on the idea to explain geological similarities between Madagascar, India, and Australia. Later on, this theory was disproved by continental drift.

If such a land really did exist though, what climate would it have? I imagine that the center of Kumari Kandam would be a hot desert similar to Australia. The coastal areas could be much more tropical. I imagine that the regions near India would have similar ecology to Sri Lanka, the regions near Madagascar would have similar ecology to that island, and the lands near Australia would resemble Australia in many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. Given that this is on a similar climate zone to Australia, I would say that the whole southern portion of this landmass would be desert as far north as Madagascar, shifting to tropical forest in the north. The southern shoreline would harbour temperate forests, (though not reaching very far inland) likely composed of eucalyptus.

as a side note, the fact that this continent apparently links Madagascar, India and Australia leads to some interesting speculation as to how it’s fauna and flora might develop; all these landmasses have been evolutionary cauldrons producing a bewildering array of species from lines of the evolutionary tree that have died out elsewhere in the world. What happens when “lemurs meet tree kangaroos meet proboscis monkeys?” Or when “dingoes meet fossa meet tigers?” Could be interesting…

Comment: The fossa would attack, probably

Comment: I'll pass on venomous monkeys or tigers with the attitude of Australian wildlife.